# Is it possible to create a OPC server that connects to a device over telnet or http?

Tags: http, telnet, opc

I have a device that can either be controlled with HTTP request or over a telnet connection. A client whats to be able to connect to this via a OPC server. Would it be possible to create a OPC server that talks directly to the device over HTTP or telnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is quite feasible. OPC servers typically convert some native device communication to OPC. I would recommend OPC UA in practice.